# Set a temporary / relative root CSS selector?

Tags: css, class, selector, root

As usual, I've Googled this and read through the documentation ([W3C's CSS Selectors documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)), but still have been unable to find an answer.

It's very difficult and almost definitely counter-productive to explain why I've set my stylesheets up this way, so I'll just show you a section of one of my CSS stylesheets and ask what I came here to ask.

I know that `.className`, for example, is a global class - it is applied to every element that uses it on all pages that the stylesheet is linked to - and that `#sectionID .className`, for example, is a local class - it is only applied to the elements that uses it inside of the element with the ID of `sectionID`.

So, is there is a way to somehow set a temporary / relative root for a style sheet, so that the following extract:

```css
#sectionID1 .className1, #sectionID1 .className2, #sectionID1 .className3, #sectionID1 a, #sectionID1 a:link, #sectionID1 a:visited, #sectionID1 a:hover, #sectionID1 a:active, #elementID2 input {
    color: #0084B4;
}
```

can become something like this:

```css
#sectionID1 .className1, .className2, .className3, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, #elementID2 input {
    color: #0084B4;
}
```

Thanks :)

(Sorry for my bad explaining and, almost definite, incorrect use of terminology :L)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but you can use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), to achieve such dynamics

Comment: Oh, that's fantastic! I've never heard of that before. Thank you! :D